# vsftpd with "encrypted private key"

Tags: encryption, rhel, vsftpd

I have created a FTPS server using `vsftpd`.

When I use an unencrypted private key, `vsftpd` works fine.

```
rsa_cert_file=/etc/vsftpd/unenc_cert.pem
```

If I have to use a certificate that contains an encrypted private key, `vsftpd` fails to start.

```
vsftpd[42062]: 500 OOPS: SSL: cannot load RSA certificate
```

Encrypted private key:

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Is there a way to use encrypted private key in `vsftpd`?

`vsftpd` version: `3.0.2`

Answer (score 2):

After researching/googling/testing, i was able to find that `vsftpd` does not have option to provide the passphrase for encrypted private key.

Options to overcome this limitation are:

- Use unencrypted private key
- Use encrypted private key and run the `vsftpd` from command line. Running `vsftpd` from command line will prompt for passphrase which should be entered manually every time.
- Use encrypted private key and implement a `expect` script to provide password and implement a new `systemd` configuration instead of the standard `vsftpd` systemd configuration.

Already this has been raised in the [bugzilla](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/10319).